# Get visible square of image/rectangle

Tags: wpf, silverlight

[image]

There is a canvas(Gray color) with an image on it (Blue color). I make some manipulations with  the image and want to find the visible part(Red color) of the image after manipulations.

For that i use this method:

```
    private double GetSquare()
            {
                Rect rect = GetBounds(Image, Canvas);
                var canvasRect = RootGeometry.Rect;
                canvasRect.Intersect(rect);
                return canvasRect.Height * canvasRect.Width;
            }
  private static Rect GetBounds(FrameworkElement of, FrameworkElement from)
        {

            // Might throw an exception if of and from are not in the same visual tree
            GeneralTransform transform = of.TransformToVisual(from);
            return transform.TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, of.ActualWidth, of.ActualHeight));

        }
```

XAML:

```
<Canvas Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ImageCanvas" Background="Gray">
            <Canvas.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry x:Name="RootGeometry"/>
            </Canvas.Clip>
            <Image  x:Name="Image" Stretch="Fill"
                   ManipulationStarted="OnManipulationStarted"
                   ManipulationDelta="OnManipulationDelta"
                   ManipulationCompleted="OnManipulationCompleted" Source="{...}" 
                   ImageOpened="OnImageOpened">
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <MatrixTransform x:Name="previousTransform" />
                            <TransformGroup x:Name="currentTransform">
                                <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform" />
                                <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" />
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </TransformGroup>

                    </Image.RenderTransform>

                </Image>
        </Canvas>
```

The method works correct for 2-d picture. But for 3-th image the method returns  incorrect result. Maybe  someone can explain why the method returns incorrect result and also explain the way how to get the visible part of  image (3-th)?